# How do I download pip for python?

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, python-3.x, pip

I am trying to download pip for python on my Mac, but I have been running into some issues. If someone could outline a better process to do this, I'd really appreciate it. Here are what I've done so far and my issue:

I followed the steps on https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/# and downloaded get-pipy.py, which placed the file in my downloads folder.

In the Terminal, I ran:

> cd ~/Downloads

And then:

> python get-pip.py

However, after some code returned, the final line was:

> OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip'

What is the reason for this error? I am still unable to access pip when attempting to use it in other code. One thing I should mention is that I have already downloaded the latest version of Python, which should have downloaded pip with it, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: `sudo python get-pip.py`

Comment: which version of **Python**? it cannot be **2.7** and **3.x**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run `get-pip.py` as a super-user; simply run the following:

```
> sudo python get-pip.py
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

`sudo easy_install pip`